# IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to type value in a edit text in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a RecyclerView in my app and I am adding items to it by searching manually like in a shopping cart. Each row has a name as well as a edit text which i can enter value. I am using an ArrayList to store data which enter in the **edit text** using TextWatcher. For example lets say I add two or three items(rows) to the RecyclerView and try to enter value not in to the first **edit text** in the first row, from the second or third item(row), I am getting an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** error. I tried lot of ways. Nothing work.

This is my Adapter class.

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<String> itemsName, itemsQty, itemsPCode, itemPlant, _retData;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;

    public SelectItemAdapter(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsPCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemPlant = new ArrayList<String>();
        _retData = new ArrayList<String>();
    }


    @Override
    public SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_selected_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));
        holder.setItemQty(itemsQty.get(position));
        holder.setItemPCode(itemsPCode.get(position));
        holder.setItemPlant(itemPlant.get(position));
        holder.numPicker.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    _retData.add(position, arg0.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public String retrieveData(int i) {
        return _retData.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsName.size();
    }

    public Object getItemName(int position) {
        return itemsName.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemQty(int position) {
        return itemsQty.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPCode(int position) {
        return itemsPCode.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPlant(int position) {
        return itemPlant.get(position);
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public void add(int location, String iName, String iQty, String iPCode, String iPlant) {
        itemsName.add(location, iName);
        itemsQty.add(location, iQty);
        itemsPCode.add(location, iPCode);
        itemPlant.add(location, iPlant);
        notifyItemInserted(location);
    }

    public void remove(int location) {
        if (location >= itemsName.size())
            return;

        itemsName.remove(location);
        notifyItemRemoved(location);
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private SelectItemAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName, txtPCode, txtAvailableQty, txtTempQty, txtPlant;
        Button bRemove;
        EditText numPicker;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, SelectItemAdapter parent) {
            super(itemView);
            this.parent = parent;
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtAvailableQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailbleQty);
            txtPCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPCode);
            txtPlant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlant);
            bRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
            numPicker = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            bRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItemName(CharSequence name) {
            textItemName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemQty(CharSequence name) {
            txtAvailableQty.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPCode(CharSequence name) {
            txtPCode.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPlant(CharSequence name) {
            txtPlant.setText(name);
        }

        public String getQtyNumber() {
            return numPicker.getText().toString();
        }

        public CharSequence getItemName() {
            return textItemName.getText();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public class RetItem {
        public String _itemNumPic;
    }

}
```

My logCat.

```
05-31 19:39:57.394 30412-30412/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
05-31 19:39:57.394 30412-30412/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-31 19:39:57.397 30412-30412/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.adapters.SelectItemAdapter$1.afterTextChanged(SelectItemAdapter.java:73)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7695)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9483)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:972)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:516)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5803)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5616)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2619)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2361)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2702)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3713)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
```

Comment: take 2 seconds to run that in a debugger with a breakpoint where the exception is thrown. you'll immediatly see that your list is empty at this point.

Comment: Yes, problem is when i try to type a value in the second row without type  value in the first this exception occur. I want a solution to **add "0"** to other places if I started not from the first place.

Comment: make sure your `_retData` has data added to it at the same time as `items*` (in the `add` method). Then use `set` instead of `add` on your `_retData` list. (better yet, use an object to hold all that data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable _retData size at the begining is 0. when you try to add item in the second position it's out of its bounds.
You have to make sure that you list is at the same size as your recycler size.
In order to do so, you  have to ways:
 1. in your add function add:

```
_retData.add(location, new String());
```

in your remove function add:

```
_retData.remove(location);
```

2. the second way, which i think is better, is to create a class called MyItem for example, and let it have the fields: Name, Qty, Pcode, Plant, retData.
then, in your recycler create a List of MyItem, and then you want have to keep an eye on its size. it's also more convenient.